git always keep one file the neweset even git-reset

In my project, there is a dev-note.md, which contains all my development note, and I want it always be 'content appened', especially, when I git reset project, it will not go back.
as the figure shows: when I git reset at step-3, the dev-mote.md still keeps as the newest-v3
Or some other recommended way to manage a file, which always 'grow up'



Do not put that file under Git control. Only a file untracked by Git can survive a reset, a branch switch, etc.

git always makes a full snapshot of the repo for each commit. Why is it wrong for you to know the exact state of the dev-note.md file over time? For me it would be confusing to have a file that never changes even though I checked out a commit from the past. If that's more like a personal journal of yours, add it to .gitignore and back it up seperately.
